# 'IEnumerable<>' does not contain a definition for 'OrderBy'

Tags: linq

> Error CS1929  'IEnumerable' does not contain a
> definition for 'OrderBy' and the best extension method overload
> 'DynamicQueryableExtensions.OrderBy(IQueryable, string, params
> object[])' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable'

I get this error for the following query.

```
var designationDtos = queryResult.Select(x =>
{
    var designationDto = ObjectMapper.Map<Designation, DesignationDto>(x.designation);
    designationDto.DepartmentName = x.department.Name;
    return designationDto;
}).OrderBy(input.Sorting).ToList();
```

The problem is with OrderBy. If I remove the orderby then things work fine. And input.Sorting is a string .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because `IEnumerable` does not have such `OrderBy`, but you have custom extension over `IQueryable` which accepts such parameters.

```cs
var designationDtos = queryResult.Select(x =>
{
    var designationDto = ObjectMapper.Map<Designation, DesignationDto>(x.designation);
    designationDto.DepartmentName = x.department.Name;
    return designationDto;
})
.AsQueryable()  
.OrderBy(input.Sorting)
.ToList();
```

Also consider to do not use Automapper in this query or finish mapping configuration, then query can be more effective.

```cs
query.ProjectTo<DesignationDto>(configuration)
   .OrderBy(input.Sorting)
   .ToList();
```